# BASH, delete from file following set pattern

Tags: regex, bash, search, grep

I have a config file which contains multiple entries.

Using bash how do I search for `New` and remove it and all of the entries relating to it.

```
Test {
   blah..

    site {
        id
    }
    location {
        id
    }
    staff {
        access {
            
        }
    }
}

New {
   blah..

    site {
        id
    }
    location {
        id
    }
    staff {
        access {
            
        }
    }
}

Link {
   blah..

    site {
        id
    }
    location {
        id
    }
    staff {
        access {
            
        }
    }
}
```

resulting in

```
Test {
   blah..

    site {
        id
    }
    location {
        id
    }
    staff {
        access {
            
        }
    }
}

Link {
   blah..

    site {
        id
    }
    location {
        id
    }
    staff {
        access {
            
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can use `grep` to find the matching results, but how would I then remove it?
E.g:

`grep -m 1 -A25 New test.txt`

**edit**
It looks like this works to remove the output and give the right result.

`grep -m 1 -A25 New test.txt > test | grep -v -x -f test test.txt` but it leaves a redundant file `test` over and the original file isn't updated.

Is there a better way to do this so there is no redundant file and the original file is updated?

Comment: From which tool/language this output comes from ?

Comment: Your file format is not obvious, but something like `sed '/New/,/^}$/d' file` would work for the sample you show.

Comment: @GillesQuénot it's from a custom in house script. That I don't have any control over.

Comment: @tripleee unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: You might try something like `awk '/^New/{f=1}/^Link/{f=0}{if(f==1){next}}1' file`

Comment: @j_b thanks this will only work if the next entry contains `Link`, that won't normally be the  case..

Comment: Alternate version no relying on presence of 'Link': `awk '/^New/{f=1}/^}/&&f==1{f=0}{if(f==1){next}}1' file`

Comment: @Tom It works for the sample you actually posted. Are there differences between what you posted in whitespace or etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `sed 's/^New/,/^}/d'` works for me. This is the output when I paste your sample through it:

```
Test {
   blah..

    site {
        id
    }
    location {
        id
    }
    staff {
        access {
            
        }
    }
}


Link {
   blah..

    site {
        id
    }
    location {
        id
    }
    staff {
        access {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split on the space between the closing `}` and the opening `\w+[^{]*{` with this regex:

```
/(?<=^\})[^{]*?(?=\w+[^{]*{)/gm
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TWeYkZ/1)

Once you have the blocks, filter out `New`. Here is a Ruby demo:

```
ruby -e 'puts $<.read.
            split(/(?<=^\})[^{]*?(?=\w+[^{]*{)/).
            select{|b| b[/\w+/]!="New"}' file
```

But you could do the same with Perl, Python, etc.

---

Alternatively, a Perl:

```
perl -0777 -pE 's/^New[\s\S]*?\}\s*(?=^\w+\h*\{)//gm' file
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pvVDjs/1) of regex

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/^New/{f=1} /^}/&&f==1 {f=0;next} !f' file.txt
```

Output:

```
Test {
   blah..

    site {
        id
    }
    location {
        id
    }
    staff {
        access {
            
        }
    }
}


Link {
   blah..

    site {
        id
    }
    location {
        id
    }
    staff {
        access {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Nice catch.  Will update accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
mawk 'BEGIN {  FS = RS "*New {"
              ORS = RS = RS "}" RS } NF < 2'
```

---

```
     1  Test {
     2     blah..
     3  
     4      site {
     5          id
     6      }
     7      location {
     8          id
     9      }
    10      staff {
    11          access {
    12              
    13          }
    14      }
    15  }
    16  
    17  Link {
    18     blah..
    19  
    20      site {
    21          id
    22      }
    23      location {
    24          id
    25      }
    26      staff {
    27          access {
    28              
    29          }
    30      }
    31  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a perl solution using a `recursive regex`:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\bNew\s*(\{(?:[^{}]+|(?1))*})//' test.txt
```

The pattern matches a sequence of string `New` followed by a *balanced*
set of curly brackets:

- `[^{}]+` matches any characters other than curly brackets.
- `(?1)` tells the regex engine to embed the parenthesized pattern
  (mentioned below) at this position.
- `(?:[^{}]+|(?1))` is an alternation of the patterns above.
- `(\{(?:[^{}]+|(?1))*})` is enclosed by a pair of curly brackets
  and is referred by `(?1)` recursively to make the pattern match
  the nested pairs of curly brackets.